# RxSwift: Need help using flatMap and reduce

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am writing a simple [Diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware) password generator to experiment with RxSwift.
I am struggling with using `flatMap` and `reduce` in separate steps.

**Current code**

I have an observable `wordCount` that is bound to the `UIStepper` value and generate a new password with a given number of words.

[image]

```
    let rawPassword = wordCount
        .asObservable()
        .map { wordCount in
            self.rollDice(numberOfDice: wordCount)
                .map { numbers in wordMap[numbers]! }
        }
```

`rollDice` returns an `Observable<String>` (for example: `["62345", "23423", "14231", ...]`) and is then mapped to words.

`rawPassword` is an `Observable<Observable<String>>`

In this example, it would be: `[["spec", "breed", "plins", "wiry", "chile", "cecil"]]`.

I then have a `reducedPassword` which `flatMap` and `reduce` to a `String`:

```
    let reducedPassword = rawPassword
        .flatMap { raw in
            raw.reduce("") { prev, value in
                let separator = "-"
                return prev == "" ? value : "\(prev)\(separator)\(value)"
            }
    }
```

This works and I end up with the string: `spec-breed-plins-wiry-chile-cecil`.

**The problem**

Now I want to change the word separator from the UI. I just want to re-apply the reduce on my `rawPassword` when the text from the `UITextField` is updated.

I am trying to use `combineLatest` to combine the `Observable<String>` for the separator with my `Observable<Observable<String>>` `rawPassword`, like this:

```
    let reducedPassword = Observable.combineLatest(rawPassword, separator.asObservable()) { raw, sep in
        raw.reduce("") { prev, value in
            return prev == "" ? value : "\(prev)\(sep)\(value)"
        }
    }
```

But the `reduce` never fires and clicking the stepper does nothing.
I have tried to `flatMap` in a separate step but then, with `combineLatest` I only end up with the last word. Is `combineLatest` the right approach at all?

Comment: why not make separator observable? possibly keep last generated words...

Comment: My separator is an `Observable<String>`, I just can't find out how to combine it with `rawPassword`.

Comment: Did my answer below not satisfy the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

The problem is that `reducedPassword` (in your `combineLatest` case) is really `Observable<Observable<String>>`.  It helps to type annotate, especially when learning `RxSwift` to ensure things are actually what you expect them to be.

```
let reducedPassword: Observable<Observable<String>> = Observable.combineLatest(rawPassword, separator.asObservable()) { // ...
```

### The Fix

So, to get your modified `reducedPassword` to work, you need to take elements coming through (`Observable<String>`) and replace the current `Observable<Observable<String>>` with it.  So use `switchLatest()` (which is like doing `flatMap { $0 }`):

```
let reducedPassword = Observable.combineLatest(rawPassword, separator.asObservable()) {
    raw, sep in

    raw.reduce("") { prev, value in
        prev == "" ? value : "\(prev)\(sep)\(value)"
    }
}
.switchLatest() // equivalent to: .flatMap { $0 }
```

### All Together

I put all of your code together, along with the fix, into something that can be run as-is with no UI:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let wordCount = BehaviorSubject<UInt>(value: 2)

let separator = BehaviorSubject<String>(value: "-")

let wordMap = ["0" : "zero", "1" : "one", "2" : "two", "3" : "three", "4" : "four"]

func rollDice(numberOfDice: UInt) -> Observable<String> {
    let maxNumber = wordMap.count
    return Observable.from(0..<numberOfDice)
        .map { _ in Int(arc4random()) % maxNumber }
        .map { String($0) }
}

let rawPassword = wordCount
    .asObservable()
    .map { wordCount in
        rollDice(numberOfDice: wordCount)
            .map { numbers in wordMap[numbers]! }
    }

let reducedPassword = Observable.combineLatest(rawPassword, separator.asObservable()) {
    raw, sep in

    raw.reduce("") { prev, value in
        prev == "" ? value : "\(prev)\(sep)\(value)"
    }
}
.switchLatest() // equivalent to: .flatMap { $0 }

reducedPassword
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })

separator.onNext("||||")
wordCount.onNext(4)
separator.onNext("___")
```

Outputs:

> zero-four
>   zero||||two
>   two||||four||||zero||||one
>   three___two___two___four

### Notes

- I'm not sure why `wordMap` is `[String : String]` instead of just `[String]`.  It seems strange to index a map with something like `wordMap["123"]` instead of `wordMap[123]`.
- It would be easier to implement and understand if you were to not use `Observable<Observable<String>>`, but rather `Observable<[String]>`.  This is why you had the problem, and even when you understand it, it's still more complex than it needs to be.
- Remember, type annotate your variables and closures to make sure you're doing what you expect.  You'll catch these issues earlier.

### Improved Solution

Here's another way you could write it, taking into account the notes I've outlined above.

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let wordCount = BehaviorSubject<UInt>(value: 2)

let separator = BehaviorSubject<String>(value: "-")

let wordMap = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"]

func rollDice(numberOfDice: UInt) -> [Int] {
    let maxNumber = wordMap.count
    return (0..<numberOfDice).map { _ in
        Int(arc4random()) % maxNumber
    }
}

let words: Observable<[String]> = wordCount
    .asObservable()
    .map { (count: UInt) -> [String] in
        return rollDice(numberOfDice: count)
            .map { roll in wordMap[roll] }
    }

let password: Observable<String> = Observable.combineLatest(words, separator.asObservable()) {
    (words: [String], separator: String) -> String in

    words.reduce("") { prev, value in
        prev == "" ? value : "\(prev)\(separator)\(value)"
    }
}

password.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })

separator.onNext("||||")
wordCount.onNext(4)
separator.onNext("___")
```